# Dailymotion search api example

Tags: json, api, dailymotion-api

Get latest videos on a specific keyword from dailymotion api 
http://api.dailymotion.com/videos

please help in search query,i am using this api search

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,thumbnail_url%2Ctitle&country=it&search=psl+2018&limit=50

but if search on dailymotion.com
http://www.dailymotion.com/search/psl%202018
its not showing same results

Answer (score 1):

DailyMotion detect country of IP and display results for the same country. In your API link, country is Italy and probably you are viewing results for Pakistan.

I have modify the country in API to Pakistan, now the results will be same.

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=id,thumbnail_url%2Ctitle&country=pk&search=psl+2018&limit=50